# Default select button in foundation group button

Tags: html, zurb-foundation-5

When my page is loading, I want to select an item automatically on my button group but I can't find the Foundation class to use.

```
<div class="button-bar">
        <ul class="button-group">
              <li><a href="#" class="small button">date</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="small button">site</a></li>
        </ul> 
</div>
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177111/how-to-make-active-button-in-foundation-zurb) speaks about Zurb-Foundation 4 ! Do you known if something has changed in Zurb-Foundation 5 ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Give <a> element autofocus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566031/give-a-element-autofocus)

Comment: I want to use the foundation class if existing and not my own class !

Comment: Foundation has defaults for :hover and :focus. You can either add your own class there, or add script to set the focus on your button.

Comment: @Neps I'm agree with you but when I execute `$('.button-group li').get(0).focus()` nothing happen !

Comment: @general03 it's because you're selecting the <li>. Add an a to the selector.

Comment: @Neps with `$('.button-group li a').get(0).focus()` I have always my button not selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use an `:focus` tag in CSS

```
.button-group li a:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And the Javascript code to focus on the link

```
$('.button-group li a').get(0).focus()
```

Thanks to @Bass Jobsen

Answer (score 1):

I think `$('.button-group li a').get(0).focus()` should work (unless you add the focus to an other element afterwards). You also will loose the focus by clicking somewhere else.

You can create your own `active` class for the buttons:

SCSS:

```
.button.active {
@extend button:hover;
}
```

CSS:

```
.button.active {
background-color: #007095;
}
```

Now you can use:

```
<li><a href="#" class="small button active">site</a></li>
```

Or with JavaScript:

```
 $('.button-group li:nth-child(2) a').addClass('active');
```

Comment: You're right, I forgot to use an `:focus` tag in CSS. I use the simplest fix below